# place an rsu in a specific edge

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I would like to place an rsu in a specific edge.

I found the id and the coordinates of the interested edge through the SUMO GUI.

I don't know how to translate the coordinates found, in the following statement:

```
*.rsu[1].mobility.x = XXX
*.rsu[1].mobility.y = YYY
*.rsu[1].mobility.z = ZZZ
```

this is the edge:

```
<edge id="23228228" from="251300048" to="256334009" priority="4" type="highway.residential" spreadType="center" shape="278.66,377.02 282.88,384.13 302.23,407.49">
        <lane id="23228228_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="28.20" shape="282.57,383.59 282.88,384.13 300.47,405.37"/>
    </edge>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lane::getShape method of TraCICommandInterface. It will give you a list of coordinates that a given lane is defined by (i.e., beginning and end points as well as any midpoints).

Comment: maybe I didn't express myself well, or I didn't understand your answer.
I need that in more points decided in sumo I return the coordinates x, y, z respective in veins, so as to be able to position my RSU at the precise points. I have seen the function getshape, but it does not take any coordinates, and does not take the identifier of a RSU.
thanks for your kindness